# Regex- How to account for no spaces between numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to scrape data from a pdf document that has lots of financial information.  I'm a beginner at using regex but I was able to find the number I was specifically looking for which is in the hundreds of millions.  However, there's no space between the end of that number and the start of the next number so I'm having a hard time not including the next number.

This is the result I'm getting:

```
['183,662,7203.004.00']
```

The number I want to scrape is 183,662,720, but as you can see, it's capturing the numbers afterwards since there is no space.

The code I'm using is `re.findall('\(line 1 minus line 2\)(\d.+?)Less',y)`.  I'll be using this for other versions of this document where there may be numbers in the tens of thousands to billions.  So that also complicates this a bit.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not posting an answer because it's not entirely clear what the conditions are but `\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+` could be a good start. It will match 1000 and above as long as the number uses a comma as the thousands separator and is preceded by a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the whole pattern, you might use:

```
\(line 1 minus line 2\)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)\d*(?:\.\d+)* Less\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(line 1 minus line 2\)` Match `(line 1 minus line 2)`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` Match 1+ digits optionally repeated by a `,` and 3 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\d*(?:\.\d+)*` Match optional digits, optionally followed by matching a `.` and digits
- `Less\b` Match  `Less` followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QFDl9D/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sQSWxl)

For example

```
import re

y = r"This is (line 1 minus line 2)183,662,7203.004.00 Less test"
print(re.findall(r"\(line 1 minus line 2\)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)\d*(?:\.\d+)* Less\b" ,y))
```

Output

```
['183,662,720']
```